# Specifying a django download link in djangorecipe with buildout

Tags: django, buildout

I want to deploy my django project using buildout, so I use [djangorecipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangorecipe/1.6), but

> It will automatically download Django

as says in the readme, and I want to have the option to specify a url to download django (i.e. from a pypi server).

I try to set it with index and find-links buildout options but when they say automatically is true.

I searched through several recipes and found out 2 djangorecipe's forks that seem go in a similar direction, these are [thechristmaspig](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/thechristmaspig/0.9.6) and [djbuild](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djbuild/1.0.4). The first left the download responsibility to the recipe zerokspot.recipe.git and the second allow to specify a svn repo. But both of them haven't recent activity (more than 2 years) and a very small community, that poor support make me out.

Can you suggest another way without hacks djangorecipe?

**UPDATE:**

I had tested with some options without success:

### [mr.developer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer):

In djangorecipe mentions use this recipe and I try with `fs` option of source but no way with an url like this:

```
[sources]
django = fs http://pypi_server/simple/
```

I tested with several settings but it seems only works with directory in file system

### [zc.recipe.egg](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.recipe.egg):

But it also use the same url of the djangorecipe and no found a way change it

**UPDATE2:**

### [gp.recipe.pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gp.recipe.pip):

Same results of zc.recipe.egg, but notice something: If remove the use of djangorecipe i.e. (commenting this section):

```
[buildout]
parts = pip

[pip]
recipe = gp.recipe.pip
install = django

#[django]
#recipe = djangorecipe
#settings = settings
```

it download django from the local pypi server. With django enabled (uncommenting `django` section and add `django` to `buildout:parts`) it download from www.djangoproject.com server.

In order to execute gp.recipe.pip first (so djangorecipe found django installed) I'm tried with two ways for refering a variable:

1. Refering a `pip`'s variable from `django` section (as explain in the section "[Automatic part selection and ordering](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/src/zc/buildout/buildout.txt#L1006)" of buildout docs)
2. Proceding with section [Extending sections (macros)](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/src/zc/buildout/buildout.txt#L1087) of buildout docs

Note that reorganize sections or change the values order in `parts` variable no matters for change the execution order.

But again no success

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The `fs` option of `mr.developer` should point to an already existing filesystem copy of Django.

Comment: Yes I had notice it and added in in my update, thanks anyway

Comment: can you explain why you cant download django with pip install?

Comment: @Alp I use buildout to minimize human steps when installs the project (maybe finally need to use fabric or a script to do that) but want to integrate installation in just one command and try to achieve it only with buildout ;) ...thanks

Comment: Yes, i just wanted to talk about fabric. Also, take a look at [docker](https://www.docker.io/) and [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) (both are combinable) for building consistent development and production environments that are reusable.

Comment: both tools you recommended seems promissory, need to learn it deeply ...thanx

Answer (score 0):

Based on the UPDATE2's comments in the question I figure to have two .cfg files: the one with only pip settings and the second for django settings. Then execute twice buildout using `-c` option to specify files. So with first buildout call it installs django from pypi server, second encounter that django has been installed and move on. This should works and maybe this is the solution, any other? thx